# How to specify camera capture in input tag using Django?

Tags: django

I'm currently developing an application using `Django`.

I want to open up camera capture directly when specified as follows in `HTML5` tag using `Django`.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera"/>
```

In this case, how can I make a field in a model?

Thanks in advance.

---

Django 3.2.9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Input attributes are set in the widget of the form field, not in the model. In your model you can simply use a FileField.

For example, using a plain form in your forms.py:

```
class Myform(forms.Form):
    myfield=forms.FileField(
        widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept': 'image/*', 'capture':'camera'})
    )
```

In case of a model form:

```
class Myform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = [myfile]
        widgets = {
            'myfile': forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept': 'image/*', 'capture':'camera'})
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a FileField type field, your model should have field like this

```
img = models.FileField(upload_to="/your-local-path")
```